# Firefox and Explorer behaving differently when displaying image with php echo

Tags: php, html

The image box on this page "http://www.ebookfetcher.com/bookdeals/index.php?pid=23" appears in Firefox and Explorer, but not Chrome and Safari. How do I make it invisible for all of them when $bookpage_coverimage is empty?

```
<a href="http://www.ebookfetcher.com" class="linkstyle"><img src="<?php echo $bookpage_coverimage ?>" width="260"></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a simple if statement in PHP.

```
<?php if($bookpage_coverimage !=""){ ?><a href="http://www.ebookfetcher.com" class="linkstyle"><img src="<?php echo $bookpage_coverimage ?>" width="260"></a><?php } ?>
```

Should do the trick, it will not output any html if its empty.

Comment: np, remember if you want to output something different if its empty you could simple add an else at the end of `}` so `else{ ?>something else<?php } ?>` Just incase you want to put a placeholder image saying, no image available for example. O, and accept the answer for anybody else with the same problem